# Rails / simplifying syntax when comparing nil or not elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, syntax

having the following condition, where `invitation_sent_at` can be nil :

```
if self.invitation_last_sent_at + 1.hour
    #then do something
end
```

I end up writing the following :

```
if (self.invitation_sent_at.presence && (self.invitation_sent_at + 1.hour) ...
```

I'm wondering if there is a cleaner syntax to handle the fact that `self.invitation_sent_at` could be nil, but without having to verify it so verbosely if it is present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the new operator **`&.`** (*the lonely operator*) like how `.try!` works in Rails.

```
if self&.invitation_last_sent_at&.+1.hour
    #then do something
end
```

This functionality was only recently added in Dec 2015 in Ruby 2.3.

Source: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/12/25/ruby-2-3-0-released

Comment: A bit weird syntax ! but i guess the issue i had wasn't that smart already. Good to know, thx

Comment: I don't know but I suppose the thought behind it is run .method1 (& if that works then) .method2 (& if that works then) .method3

Answer (score 1):

There is no purpose in using the `+` operator in the conditional expression the way you have shown (not storing the result).

```
if invitation_sent_at
  # do something
end
```

is equivalent to

```
if invitation_sent_at && (invitation_sent_at + 1.hour)
  # do something
end
```

In both cases the branch is taken when `invitation_sent_at` is not nil, and skipped when the value is nil.

Answer (score 0):

If the concern is that `invitation_sent_at` could be nil, you can drop #presence and just write:

```
if self.invitation_sent_at && self.invitation_sent_at + 1.hour
```

Comment: Okay; there is nothing that would failsafely permit the omission of the first verification ?

Comment: yeah, you could use #try, or even better lonely operator describe in another answer below, to safely try to add 1.hour to nil. But the answer below is also correct, that you're not actually doing anything here -- adding 1.hour to invitation_sent_at and then just throwing the result away. the value for invitation_sent_at will still be the same. if you wanted to store the value you could do `new_val = invitation_sent_at&.+1.hour`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
self.invitation_sent_at.blank? ? "" : (self.invitation_sent_at + 1)...
```